# How to replace multiple values with jq without duplicating the results?

Tags: json, jq, edit

I am attempting to update certain properties of a JSON file based on a few conditions:

- The name of the attribute must contain the string "Description".
- The attribute's `ismydata` property must be `true`.
- The attribute's `deprecatedVersion` must have an empty string for its value.

An example JSON that I am trying to update is shown here:

```
{
  "name": "account",
  "description": "Some description",
  "attributes": {
   "accountNameCode": {
      "description": "Name of the account type.",
      "type": "string",
      "ismydata": true,
      "deprecatedVersion": ""
    },
    "accountNameDescription": {
      "description": "Description of the account type.",
      "type": "string",
      "ismydata": true,
      "deprecatedVersion": ""
    },
    "anotherDescription": {
      "description": "Some other thing.",
      "type": "string",
      "ismydata": true,
      "deprecatedVersion": ""
    }
  }
}
```

At the moment, I've got the following script that is *almost* what is needed, however it duplicates the JSON body with each match that is found:

```
(.attributes 
| with_entries( select(.key|contains("Description"))) 
| keys[] as $k | .[$k] 
| select(.ismydata==true) and select(.deprecatedVersion=="") | $k) as $matchKey
| .attributes[$matchKey].description as $description
| .attributes[$matchKey].deprecatedVersion |= "Y"
| .attributes[$matchKey].description |= "Deprecated- this has been replaced by... " + $description
```

This results in the following -

```
{
  "name": "account",
  "description": "Some description",
  "attributes": {
    "accountNameCode": {
      "description": "Name of the account type.",
      "type": "string",
      "ismydata": true,
      "deprecatedVersion": ""
    },
    "accountNameDescription": {
      "description": "Deprecated- This property has been replaced by the enumerationDataType.description field. Description of the account type.",
      "type": "string",
      "ismydata": true,
      "deprecatedVersion": "Y"
    },
    "anotherDescription": {
      "description": "Some other thing.",
      "type": "string",
      "ismydata": true,
      "deprecatedVersion": ""
    }
  }
}
{
  "name": "account",
  "description": "Some description",
  "attributes": {
    "accountNameCode": {
      "description": "Name of the account type.",
      "type": "string",
      "ismydata": true,
      "deprecatedVersion": ""
    },
    "accountNameDescription": {
      "description": "Description of the account type.",
      "type": "string",
      "ismydata": true,
      "deprecatedVersion": ""
    },
    "anotherDescription": {
      "description": "Deprecated- This property has been replaced by the enumerationDataType.description field. Some other thing.",
      "type": "string",
      "ismydata": true,
      "deprecatedVersion": "Y"
    }
  }
}
```

- which shows a copy of the whole structure for each match of my conditions. How do I condense this into a single output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the problem description and sample code, it appears you are basically trying to update .attributes; the simplest approach would probably be to use the form: `.attributes |= ...`

In fact, the following appears to be a solution:

```
.attributes |=
  with_entries(
    if (.key|contains("Description")) 
        and .value.ismydata == true
        and .value.deprecatedVersion == ""
    then .value |= 
      ((.deprecatedVersion = "Y")
       | .description |= "Deprecated- this has been replaced by... \(.)")
    else .
    end)
```

---

(This solution is quite similar to the one suggested by @Newpaw but subsequently deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution can be salvaged by using `reduce` over $matchKey:

```
  reduce (
     .attributes
     | ( with_entries( select(.key|contains("Description"))) 
         | keys[] as $k | .[$k] 
         | select(.ismydata==true) and select(.deprecatedVersion=="") | $k)) as $matchKey (.;
       .attributes[$matchKey].deprecatedVersion = "Y"
     | .attributes[$matchKey].description |= "Deprecated- this has been replaced by... \(.)" )
```